# Make Kong Manger GUI to make call to /kong-manager

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kong-ingress

I have install kong using below command:

```
helm install kong kong/kong  --set admin.useTLS=false,admin.enabled=true,admin.http.enabled=true
```

I then created ingress for `admin` and `manager`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kong-admin-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'kong'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /kong-admin
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: kong-kong-admin
                port:
                  number: 8001
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kong-manager-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'kong'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /kong-manager
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: kong-kong-manager
                port:
                  number: 8002
```

But when I nagigate to `http://localhost/kong-manager`, I get below errors:

[image]

How I can make the `kong-manager` to make the request to `localhost/kong-manager` rather `http://localhost`?

I found below link, but not sure how to do that with `helm` values:
https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/kong-manager/enable/

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, I can pass the host/path of manager and admin api as env values:

```
helm install kong kong/kong  --set admin.useTLS=false,admin.enabled=true,admin.http.enabled=true,env.admin_gui_path=/kong-manager,env.admin_gui_url=http://localhost/kong-manager,env.admin_gui_api_url=http://localhost/kong-admin
```